# Linear Probing Overwriting Records in C

Tags: c, file, file-io, hashtable, linear-probing

I am trying to implement linear probing for collision resolution for a hash table in C. I am inserting and retrieving the information from a file using the RRN (record relative number) to locate the index where each register will be inserted/retrieved. Initially, I am setting all the index values to "_" as a way to mark them as empty. So far, so good. The bump I have come across is when I actually attempt to implement the collision resolution. The program seems to be overwriting the record that was there instead of looking for the next available spot. Also, when I purposefully look for a record with a non-existent key (name), the program gets stuck.

I am setting the pointer back to the beginning of the file whenever fd=0 (when it reaches the end of the file, in other words), but something tells me this might be the problem. Can you guys take a look? Thanks in advance:

```
//Simplified data struct that will be used
struct client{
char last_name[15];
char maiden_name[15];
char name[15];
}client

//Hash function
int Hash(char nm[15]){
    int key, sum = 0, i;
    //Sums the ASCII values of each letter in the client's name
        for (i=0;nm[i]!='\0';i++){
       sum=sum+nm[i];
        }
    key=sum%10; // Divides the sum by 10 and saves the modulus value in key variable
    return key;
}
```

I am omitting some code for clarity's sake, but this is where I implement a while loop to verify whether a register is empty:

```
key= Hash(buff.name); // Uses Hash function to get key (index) value of where record will be stored
beginning=key;

lseek(fd, sizeof(client) * key, SEEK_SET); // Moves pointer to insert location
              read(fd, &read_buf, sizeof (client)); // Reads the record contents in memory

while((strcmp("_",read.name)) != 0){ // While record is not empty...
            ++key; //Increase the key value
            lseek(fd, sizeof (client) * key,SEEK_SET); // Change pointer to new location
            read(fd, &read_buf, sizeof (client));   // Read contents into memory again
                if (fd==0){ //If file descriptor reaches end of file, set key back to the beginning
                key=0;
                }
                if (key== beginning){ // If key reaches the origin location of the search, print out error and exit                                                                    
                printf("There are no more spaces in the file!");
                break;
                }
}

write(fd, &buff, sizeof client);
printf("The record has been inserted successfully!\n");
```

Comment: When you mention a "memory-based" version do you mean I should load the whole file contents into memory to do the search as opposed to loading in one index at a time?

Comment: Hmm, I initially set the key variable to the return value of the Hash function (Line 1 of 2nd code segment). If the while statement is not true (register is blank), it goes straight to writing the buffer contents into that index register. If the while statement holds, then it increases the key value by one to look in the next index and then reads the contents from there. So I think the key variable already has a value when the first lseek call is made outside of the while loop, no?

Comment: Sorry, I need more coffee ...